# How to remove border in custom AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create custom `AlertDialog` with an image text and buttons. When I display it I get a white border which looks horrible.

[image]

How can I get rid of that white border?

Here my custom Dialog:

```
public LinearLayout customeLL;
    public void  alertD()
    {
        AlertDialog ad;
        AlertDialog.Builder  builder;
        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
        TextView a = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        a.setText("Test dialog");
        ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottombar_bg);
        LinearLayout customeLL = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        customeLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        customeLL.addView(img,curWidth,37);
        customeLL.addView(a,curWidth,37);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myClass.this);
        builder.setView(customeLL);
        ad=builder.create();
        ad.show();

    }
```

As you can see the topborder and image have a space in 2-3 px.

Comment: what do you mean by white boreder?

Comment: just a border . Border in alertDialog ( default it's white border)

Comment: you can use Dialog instead of Alert..?

Comment: sure, if there i can remove folder :(. But all guys said me i must create custom in alertdialog . (for image instead title) . I want just  have in vertical style  : image (instead title) , text1,text2,text3,btn1,btn2  ....

Comment: you can add layout in Dialog whatever you want..

Comment: yeah, but - how about border? or title ? how to set in dialog image instead title ????

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this use Dialog Instead of AlertDialog.Builder

.. for remove border line from Dialog..

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Comment: thanks,but it's remove only title. I need remove border :(( Please see on image in top-  white line - it's possible to remove  ?????

Comment: I've just published a gist showing a floating Dialog with custom theme, no title or border: https://gist.github.com/2643546

Answer (score 2):

This will remove borders:

```
AlertDialog ad;
ad= new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
ad.show();
ad.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout); // set your custom layout

// Then initialize your dialog views like this
TextView txt= (TextView) ad.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text); // a TextView inside dialog 
                                                            // layout
txt.setText("I'm a custom dialog!");
```

Also, I had a problem using a custom Dialog in full screen mode. my phone's notification bar kept showing up as long as the dialog wasn't dismissed. with a customized AlertDialog, this won't be an issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Dialog Border to appear in any colour you wish you have to use layout style and a theme. There is an excellent article about it here: http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/