# custom dialog border is always white

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progresscontent"
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:padding="5dp" 
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressmessage"
            style="@style/DialogText.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="40dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="@color/codeFont"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying create my own custom dialog but there is one problem here. Custom dialog border is always showing white color, what's the problem here. Any help please.
[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot?

Comment: You can try  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910239/how-to-remove-border-in-custom-alertdialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Dialog Border to appear in any colour you wish you have to use **layout style** and a **theme**. There is an excellent article about it here: http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/