# custom dialog border is always white color

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progresscontent"
        android:layout_width="266dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
                android:padding="5dp" 
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressmessage"
            style="@style/DialogText.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="40dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="@color/codeFont"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying create my own custom dialog but there is one problem here. Custom dialog border is always showing white color, what's the problem here. Any help please. In that picture shown the border is white. What should I do to remove that white border
[image]

Comment: Just check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910239/how-to-remove-border-in-custom-alertdialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

remove margin  `android:layout_margin="8dp"` from parent layout margin always move View along with background , so parent/default background will fill this position . use padding instead